# Spreading a column to match another column in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to match the rows of the dividend column with the matching value in the cells in the ticker column.

I have attached a picture of part of the spread sheet I am referring to.

There are 65 values in the dividend column and over 3000 in the ticker columns, however, each dividend has a matching value in the ticker column. What I would like to do is write something in VBA that can put the matching items in the same rows facilitating calculations.

Thank you very much for any advice.

***Picture of part of spreadsheet:***

[image]

Comment: Sorry - I hadn't noticed that the header was not titled 'dividend'. It is the column highlighted in red (from conditional formatting that finds matches).

Comment: While you can do it by formula why you prefer to use VBA?

Comment: I have to do it repeatedly for spreadsheets that have different dimensions, so I am trying to do it adaptively.

Comment: @Milan1899 what is the working formula in your cells? So that we can convert it to vba.

Comment: Sorry, Milan, but this looks like you abstracted the task until it has become impossible. As I understand it the red column is part of another worksheet with some 3000 rows and you wish to have data from at least one of those columns in your worksheet with 65 rows. That can easily be done with a VLOOKUP formula, which can be designed to make it "adaptive". Once you copied the 3000 ticker names to the same worksheet where the ticker names occupy the column where you want to write extracted data all chances of adaptivity are blown. Please give us the real setup as you have it.